# Extracting data from JSON from a webserver with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'd like to extract specific values of a JSON file pulled from a webserver.
Given the below JSON structure I'd like to extract values of "red", "yellow" and "green" but only where grp=DEF. So the output of the JS would be "40, 50, 60".
I have the following code right now and I don't know how to continue:

```
function myFunction() {
$.getJSON('http://example.com/json.php', {method: "getnumbers"}, function(data) {
```

I have the following JSON structure

```
[
  {
    "grp": "ABC",
    "red": "10",
    "yellow": "20",
    "green" : "30",
  },
  {
    "grp": "DEF",
    "red": "40",
    "yellow": "50",
    "green" : "60",
  },
  {
    "grp": "GHI",
    "red": "70",
    "yellow": "80",
    "green" : "90",
  }
]
```

Comment: Loop over (or `find()`) the returned array to find the object with `DEF` as the value for `grp`, and then output the values for `red`, `yellow`, and `green` for that object.

Comment: The thing you gotta do is iterate over the data to find the object for which grp = DEF. Once you find that you can access the values of "red", "yellow" and "green" using the same object.

You can use the find() function available on arrays to find the object that matches the condition.

Comment: The bad thing is that I never learned JS, I would like very few things every now and then so I cannot understand anything really but complete code. Yeah I know it's like you're doing my job :(

Answer (score 0):

Write a `find` function to find the item where `grp` equals to `DEF`.

```js
var js = [
  {
    "grp": "ABC",
    "red": "10",
    "yellow": "20",
    "green" : "30",
  },
  {
    "grp": "DEF",
    "red": "40",
    "yellow": "50",
    "green" : "60",
  },
  {
    "grp": "GHI",
    "red": "70",
    "yellow": "80",
    "green" : "90",
  }
];

var foundObj = js.find(function(o){
  return o.grp === 'DEF';
});

console.log(foundObj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = [
  {
    "grp": "ABC",
    "red": "10",
    "yellow": "20",
    "green" : "30",
  },
  {
    "grp": "DEF",
    "red": "40",
    "yellow": "50",
    "green" : "60",
  },
  {
    "grp": "GHI",
    "red": "70",
    "yellow": "80",
    "green" : "90",
  }
];


// the grp you're looking for
var grp = 'DEF' ;

// iterate over each element in the array
for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
  // look for the entry with a matching `grp` value
  if (obj[i].grp == grp){
     // we found it
    // obj[i].name is the matched result
  }
}
```